# $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that sends $(t,x)$ to $tx$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

To prove something for my Topology class, I need to use the fact that $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$
(t,x)\mapsto tx
$$
is continuous, where $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ has the product topology. I don't know how to show this. I see that this function is separately continuous but I don't want to use some deep separately continuous theorem to prove that it's continuous. Is there a direct way to show that it's continuous?

Thanks!

Comment: What definition of continuity are you working with? Preimages of open sets? $\varepsilon$-$\delta$?

Comment: It's in the topology setting so I'd like to use the topology definition of continuity.

Comment: @Coco: So, just to be clear, are you thinking of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n$ as having the product topology?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. @Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for a given norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$ \Vert tx-sy\Vert=\Vert t(x-y)+(t-s)y\Vert\leq\vert t\vert \Vert x-y\Vert+\vert t-s\vert\Vert y\Vert.$$

Comment: I think the op could benefit from elaboration on how this actually proves their claim (from the open-sets, topological viewpoint), but you're completely right of course

Comment: Thank you! I can prove the statement from this hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let an open set $U\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, such that $f(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R^n)\cap U\neq \varnothing$. Suppose a $(t,x)\in f^{-1}(U)$. Then there exists an $ε>0$, such that $B(tx, ε)\subseteq U$. For $0<δ<\min \{1, \frac{ε}{|x|+|t|+1}\}$ and $(t',x')=f^{-1}(t'x')\in B((t,x), δ)$ we have
$$|tx-t'x'|\leq |t-t'||x|+|t'||x-x'|\leq |t-t'|(|x|+|x-x'|)+|t||x-x'|\leq 
(|x|+\sqrt{|t-t'|^2+|x-x'|^2})\sqrt{|t-t'|^2+|x-x'|^2}+|t|\sqrt{|t-t'|^2+|x-x'|^2}=(|x|+|(t,x)-(t',x')|+|t|)|(t,x)-(t',x')|<(|x|+δ+|t|)δ\leq (|x|+1+|t|)δ<ε.$$

Therefore $t'x'\in B((t,x),ε)$, thus $(t',x')\in f^{-1}(U)$, which means that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.